# How to add a data-test-id for each record of a list

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I am writing an automated test in Cypress to test updating a record in a list of records. I want to test the last record created in the list.

I have tried adding a data-test-id (**attr.data-test-id="project-{{id}}"**) to the HTML and referenced it in my Cypress test.

HTML:

```
      <mat-list-item
        *ngFor="let project of projects; let id=index"
        (click)="selected.emit(project)"
        attr.data-test-id="project-{{id}}">
        <h3 mat-line>
          {{project.title}}
        </h3>
        <p mat-line>
          {{project.details}}
        </p>
```

Cypress test:

```
  describe('#update', () => {
    it('updates a record', (id) => {
      cy.get('[attr.data-test-id="project-${id}"]').click()

    });
```

I want to pass the index number (id) in the Cypress test, however, I am receiving a "Syntax error, unrecognized expression" message in Cypress. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `cy.contains('mat-list-item', 'text-of-the-item-i-want-to-test').click()` or `cy.get('mat-list-item').eq(6).click()` (assuming e.g you want the 7th item). There's no way to parametize the `it()` callback, so you have to define the position in another way.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with Angular, but from it seems the `attr.data-` is angular-specific template syntax. The actual HTML it'll produce is going to be standard `data-` attribute.

Thus, you need to query using:

```js
cy.get(`[data-test-id="project-${id}"]`).click()
```

Also make sure you use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (using backticks: `` `string` ``), otherwise your variable `id` won't get interpolated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code and check the test is running fine.  For the dollar symbol `$` can you add `Cypress.$` and give a try with the below code:

```
describe('Some update', () => {
        it('updates a record', (id) => {
          cy.get('[data-test-id="project-Cypress.${id}"]').click()
        });
```